# Using React, Quiz Implementation - animation is working a little “strange”

Tags: css, reactjs

I've made a quiz app using React: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-kare-gczfw

Would be awesome to get some feedback, especially the animation that happens when the "next" button is clicked. I realized that the animation happens initially, then does not happen, then happens again. Wondering what I'm missing to make the animation happen at all times when next is clicked.

I've created an "animation" state field in the Quiz component so that it goes from false to true, and vice versa.

```
class Quiz extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentQuiz: 0,
    numOfQuestions: 0,
    score: 0,
    resultSummary: false,
    animation: false
  };

  handleNextQuestion = answer => {
    const { currentQuiz, numOfQuestions, score } = this.state;

    if (answer) {
      this.setState({
        score: score + 1,
        numOfQuestions: numOfQuestions + 1
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        numOfQuestions: numOfQuestions + 1
      });
    }

    if (numOfQuestions === quizzes[currentQuiz].questions.length - 1) {
      this.setState({
        numOfQuestions,
        resultSummary: true
      });
    }

    if (!this.state.animation) {
      this.setState({ animation: "multiple-choices" });
    } else {
      this.setState({ animation: false });
    }
  };

  handleNextQuiz = () => {
    const { currentQuiz } = this.state;

    if (currentQuiz + 1 === quizzes.length) {
      this.setState({
        resultSummary: false,
        numOfQuestions: 0,
        score: 0,
        currentQuiz: 0
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        resultSummary: false,
        numOfQuestions: 0,
        score: 0,
        currentQuiz: currentQuiz + 1
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const {
      currentQuiz,
      numOfQuestions,
      score,
      resultSummary,
      animation
    } = this.state;

    const { title, questions } = quizzes[currentQuiz];
    const currentQuestion = questions[numOfQuestions];

    const shuffledAnswerChoices = shuffle([
      ...currentQuestion.incorrectAnswers,
      currentQuestion.correctAnswer
    ]);

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <h1>{title}</h1>
        {resultSummary ? (
          <Result
            score={score}
            numOfQuestions={numOfQuestions}
            nextQuizHandler={this.handleNextQuiz}
          />
        ) : (
          <Question
            currentQuestion={currentQuestion}
            shuffledAnswerChoices={shuffledAnswerChoices}
            nextQuestionHandler={this.handleNextQuestion}
            animation={animation}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Quiz;
```

Also wondering if 1) there is a better way of managing state in this app and 2) tips on media queries for mobile devices (I'm sort of new to responsive design).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React.js [setState is asynchronous](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#when-is-setstate-asynchronous) and [batches/defers](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) the state updates resulting in the component not updating instantly. This can result in your state changes becoming out of sync and in your case the `handleNextQuestion` function has potentially 3 `setState` calls which really rely on each other in order to render the component how you like.

I would recommend to use a [callback function](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/how-to-use-the-setstate-callback-in-react) with your setState so the callback function will happen after the setState has been applied.

```
handleNextQuestion = answer => {
...
this.setState({
  score: score + 1,
  numOfQuestions: numOfQuestions + 1
}, this.applyAnimation);

}
....

applyAnimation() {
  return !this.state.animation ? this.setState({ animation: "multiple-choices" }) : this.setState({ animation: false });
}
```

Another way to improve your code would be to bundle up your state changes and apply them together rather than 3 seperate calls in one function. There are animation libraries out there such as [react-transition-group](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html) which can help with animation state changes.

For tips on media queries, focus on building [mobile-first responsive css](https://zellwk.com/blog/how-to-write-mobile-first-css/) so you only override styling for small, medium and large screens for example. It will reduce the amount of code required to build responsive components. Also use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) as much as possible.

Comment: I've tried the callbacks after setState but it still does the same thing...

Comment: Are you combining all your state changes in one go? I realised the example I gave above had a setState in the callback. I would avoid this so react only deals with one state change (score, numbQuestions and animation) - all happen at once. Give react-transition-group a go using onEnter and onExit.

Comment: I'm giving react-transition-group a go right now checking the docs you've suggested ended up wrapping <ReactCSSTransitionGroup> around <Question ... /> in the return statement and added transitionEnter={true} transitionEnterTimeout={500} transitionLeave={true} transitionLeaveTimeout={300} and css but there is no animation - can components be wrapped to have animation happen for the entire component?

Comment: Yeah a CSS transition group wraps one component. The component may also contain other components. I would recommend to setup there example in a test and try to replicate in your code, you are pretty close. Usually transitions occur on each list item or a parent component 
when changing routes for example. https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/v1-stable/README.md#high-level-api-csstransitiongroup